# Using Font Awesome icon inside of a Bootstrap 4 Card

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am a newbie with Bootstrap 4 and am getting stuck on something that is hopefully simple - I have searched here and read the bootstrap examples but didn't see what I need.

I am looking to put a font awesome icon inside of a card.  Here is my sample code:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-block">
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</div>
<p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? It should work fine providing you've included Font Awesome with Bootstrap: https://www.codeply.com/go/C4GnRkIG9r

Comment: Hi, yes I probably should have clarified - I just don't get much of anything. :-) http://webdevtemp.us/reports/index.html

Comment: Please read ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It looks like you need clean-up the code, and take a step back with understanding HTML, Bootstrap and Fontawesome basics before posting questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML head section you attempt to load the Font Awesome stylesheet:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

This attempt does not include the rel attribute, and in my browser as soon as I set it to stylesheet the font awesome icons appear:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```